# UWP TemplateBinding in ControlTemplate to fixed value

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to bind a property (myHeight) in my Controltemplate to the parent. The following is my code so far.

**Resource dict**

```
<Style TargetType="local2:TestingControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local2:TestingControl">
                <Border
                    Height="{TemplateBinding myHeight}"
                    Background="Green"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel>                            
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**TestingControl.cs**

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Content")]
public sealed class TestingControl : Control
{
    public TestingControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TestingControl);
    }

    public static readonly double myHeight = (double)100;

    public object Content
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(string), typeof(TestingControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

What i'm trying to bind is the myHeight. I'd like to have this in the .cs since I need to run some operations on it. This fails to load entirely!

---

I also tried the following approach

**Resource dict**

```
<x:Double x:Key="myHeight">100</x:Double>
<Style TargetType="local2:TestingControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local2:TestingControl">
                <Border
                    Height="{ThemeResource myHeight}"
                    Background="Green"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**TestingControl.cs**

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Content")]
public sealed class TestingControl : Control
{
    public TestingControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TestingControl);

        var x  = (double)Resources["myHeight"];
    }

    public object Content
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(string), typeof(TestingControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

The problem with the second approach, is that when reading the property in the .cs code, `var x  = (double)Resources["myHeight"];` I get an exception.

Resolutions to either (preferably both, since I'm just trying to learn UWP) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is TemplateBinding should bind the dependency property and you write the static filed that can not bind to Height.

The second thing is ThemeResource will find the Theme but you define a static source.

```
<x:Double x:Key="myHeight">100</x:Double>
<Style TargetType="local2:TestingControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local2:TestingControl">
                <Border
                    Height="{StaticResource myHeight}"
                    Background="Green"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The third thing is you get the resource at first but the resource inits after OnApplyTemplate.

You should move the code that gets the resource to OnApplyTemplate.

```
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        try
        {
            // find something in TestingControl.Resources
            var x = Resources["myHeight"];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        try
        {
            // find something in App.Resources
            var x = App.Current.Resources["myHeight"];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
```

If your resource is written in App.xaml that you should use App.Current.Resources to get the resource.

If you want to get the resource in your customs control that you should add the resource in your control.

```
    <local:TestingControl>
        <local:TestingControl.Resources>
            <x:Double x:Key="myHeight">100</x:Double>
        </local:TestingControl.Resources>
    </local:TestingControl>
```

Comment: I assume you meant StaticResource not StaticSource. Unfortunately, accessing in the OnApplyTemplate() still didn't work

Comment: I created a resource dictionary and included it in the app.xaml file.

Comment: As for the accessor of myHeight, it's in the TestingControl class

Comment: If your resource is written in App.xaml that you should use App.Current.Resources to get the resource

Comment: Fantastic that solves the problem. How should I have declared the resource as a part of TestingControl? As far as i can tell TestingControl does not have a resources section, since it's defined in a template. I have tried accessing <ControlTemplate.Resources> but it seems that doesn't exist

Comment: Update it. If you want to get the resource in your customs control that you should add the resource in your control.

Comment: Right. So there's no way to just have a default set of resources for that control?

Comment: Also, it would be awesome if you could tell me how I should've had the binding in my first approach. I understand that TemplateBinding should be used with dependency properties, but Binding didn't work either. I also tried specifying the relative parent as follows: {Binding Content.myHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}

Comment: It is the feature in UWP?

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand. Yes - this is a UWP project.